# ssh set up gre tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I'm trying to create a GRE tunnel between a local Linux Mint 18.3 VM ("`ServerA`") running in my VirtualBox, and a remote Ubuntu 18.04 server ("`ServerB`") running in another location. A firewall is in between which only allows port 22 from `ServerA` to `ServerB`. Also, `ServerA` is using a NAT interface in VirtualBox; so locally the IP belonging to `ServerA` is `10.0.2.15`, but it is being NAT'd to the IP of the host, which is, for simplicity, `1.1.1.1/24`. I am able to ssh from `ServerA` to `ServerB`, so I think I may be able to set up the GRE tunnel with `ssh`'s `-w` option, but I'm not fully understanding how to set it up. Here is one of many things I've tried. The IP of `ServerB` is, for simplicity, `2.2.2.2/24`.

```
ServerA> sudo ip tunnel add tun0 mode gre local 1.1.1.1 remote 2.2.2.2 ttl 255
ServerA> sudo ip addr add 10.10.10.1/30 dev tun0
ServerA> sudo ip link set tun0 up

ServerB> sudo ip tunnel add tun0 mode gre local 2.2.2.2 remote 1.1.1.1 ttl 255
ServerB> sudo ip addr add 10.10.10.2/30 dev tun0
ServerB> sudo ip link set tun0 up

ServerA> ssh -Nf -w 0:0 root@2.2.2.2
```

I was hoping that `-w 0:0` would have `ssh` tie the `tun0` interface of my local VM with the `tun0` interface of the remote server. However, when I try that, I get the following:

```
# ssh -w 0:0 root@2.2.2.2 
root@2.2.2.2's password: 
Tunnel device open failed.
Could not request tunnel forwarding.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT - Potential Solution**

I found another thread (but lost the link) where a slightly different approach was taken.  I may post it as an answer later if it pans out, but so far it looks like it is working.  Instead of creating a `tunnel` interface it creates a `taptun` interfaces.

```
ServerA> sudo ip taptun add tun0 mode tun
ServerA> sudo ip addr add 10.10.10.1/30 dev tun0
ServerA> sudo ip link set tun0 up

ServerB> sudo ip taptun add tun0 mode tun
ServerB> sudo ip addr add 10.10.10.2/30 dev tun0
ServerB> sudo ip link set tun0 up

ServerA> ssh -Nf -w 0:0 root@2.2.2.2
```

This works and establishes the tunnel.  I just need to see how different it is from GRE and if it will work for my application.